# What does the phrase "eat sand" mean?

Tags: word-usage

There is a dialogue in a deleted scene from Cameron's Titanic movie. At the last moment of the sinking, a senior wireless operator continues to send an SOS signal. And then a young operator comes in, carrying a lifejacket for him and says "Come on, let's clear out. We've done our duty. We're gonna be **eating sand** for breakfast." But the senior operator ignores him and keeps signaling a distress code. What does the phrase "eat sand" mean?

Answer (score 11):

It probably means 'die by drowning', famously the fate of 68% of those on board the ship, and the certain fate of those who remained at their posts until the ship sank. There is often sand at the bottom of the sea, or on beaches where drowned corpses are washed up by the tide. The expression sounds like a variant of 'bite the dust' which can mean 'die'. Alternatively, 'eat sand for breakfast' could mean 'be in a very bad situation' (e.g. stuck in a lifeboat with no food).

Whatever, you don't want to eat sand for breakfast. It is an unappetising prospect.

On board the real life Titanic, similar words were said by James McElroy, the ship's chief purser, who was last seen organising the loading of passengers into lifeboats, and who is believed to have remained on board until the ship sank. The last words anyone heard him say, to Second Officer Charles Lightoller, were "Good-bye, I wish you luck. Well, it looks as if we will have sand for breakfast tomorrow."

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thank you very much.